# Problema com a Codificação de Caracteres UTF-8 / ISO-8859-1

Tags: php, html, codificação-de-caracteres, utf-8, iso-8859-1

Eu desenvolvi um site e quando eu uso:

```
    header("Content-Type: text/html;  charset=utf-8", true);
```

os caracteres do PHP funcionam perfeitamente, mas os do HTML não, ficam com **pontos de interrogação**. Mas quando eu uso o código abaixo, acontece exatamente o contrário ou seja, funciona normal no HTML mas não no PHP:

```
    header("Content-Type: text/html;  charset=ISO-8859-1", true);
```

Alguém pode me ajudar por favor?

Comment: No `html` coloque `<meta charset="UTF-8">` dentro do `head`, assim o utf-8 irá funcionar nos 2

Comment: Você está salvando o HTML com encoding errado, só isso.  O problema está na configuração do editor de código. Qual editor está usando? Acerte o encoding do editor para bater com o que você deseja usar, antes de salvar o código, ou use entities, que independem de encoding. É uma das coisas mais bem boladas do HTML, e não muda com encoding nenhum, se bem que se a pessoa domina o que está fazendo e tem controle sobre o ambiente, pode ser desnecessário.

Comment: Não é possível determinar uma solução sem analisar os seus arquivos. Pois pode ser o que o Bacco comentou tal como também pode ser dados provindos de um banco de dados ou outra fonte (txt, json, etc) que estejam com charset iso..  Mas faça o mais básico e simples,  verificando como que o seu editor de texto está salvando os arquivos, tanto php, quanto html.  Apenas evite tentar resolver isso com htmlentities() ou utf8_encode().

Comment: @DanielOmine lembrando que o utf8_encode() é uma função de adaptação de sistemas em encodings diferentes. Num site normal isso não deve ser usado. A razão de existir o utf8_encode e utf8_decode é apenas compatibilização quando você não tem controle sobre alguma das partes. Se a aplicação é inteira sua, provavelmente é o caso de conversão dos dados na origem (trabalhar com tudo no mesmo encoding), e não no fluxo. Quanto ao entities, eu até gosto, mas quando a origem de dados tem problema, pode confundir mais ainda (pq o html_entities depende do encoding certo).

Comment: Agora, usar entities no HTML eu acho prático (literal, escrevendo por exemplo `acentua&ccedil;&atilde;o` em vez de `acentuação`), pois nesse caso, como não é conversão, fica bom em qualquer encoding.